# Vulkan: Is the pImageIndex of vkAcquireNextImageKHR definitely returned in order?

Tags: vulkan

Since I am using multi-threaded secondary command buffer records, if the pImageIndex of vkAcquireNextImageKHR is definitely returned in order then I can submit the estimated pImageIndex to the secondary command buffer before calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no guarantee of what the next image will be; if there was, there'd be no point in returning an index to begin with. You will have to call this function on one thread and pass the image index to some other thread with appropriate inter-thread communication mechanisms.